# Fatal error given by Matlab GUI

Tags: user-interface, matlab

***Edited Post***

These are the new functions that I have created using your template to help me out.
What is happening is though the code works fine, the 'check for cursor' boxes are not over top of the axes. In fact they are very far off. I used disp(axPos) once with set(hAx, 'Units','pixels'), and once with it commented out. It displayed:

1.

```
 169.0000   71.0000  126.0000   51.0000
 94.0000  122.0000  126.0000   51.0000
 19.0000   71.0000  126.0000   51.0000
 94.0000   20.0000  126.0000   51.0000
```

Which is the GUIDE co ordinates of the axis but not the co ordinates that are being displayed for 'Currentpoint'

2.

```
33.6000    5.3846   25.2000    3.9231
18.6000    9.3077   25.2000    3.9231
3.6000    5.3846   25.2000    3.9231
18.6000    1.4615   25.2000    3.9231
```

I do not know where these come from but are closer to where they need to be but are ~60 pixels to the left.

Here is the code:

```
function HVACSM_OpeningFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles, varargin)
% This function has no output args, see OutputFcn.
% hObject    handle to figure
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
% varargin   command line arguments to HVACSM (see VARARGIN)

% Choose default command line output for HVACSM
handles.output = hObject;
NUM = 4;

imgOff1 = imread('cond.png');
imgOn1 = imread('condH.png');

imgOff2 = imread('comp.png');
imgOn2 = imread('compH.png');

imgOff3 = imread('evap.png');
imgOn3 = imread('evapH.png');

imgOff4 = imread('exp.png');
imgOn4 = imread('expH.png');

imgOff = cell(1,NUM);
imgOff{1} = imgOff1;
imgOff{2} = imgOff2;
imgOff{3} = imgOff3;
imgOff{4} = imgOff4;

imgOn = cell(1,NUM);
imgOn{1} = imgOn1;
imgOn{2} = imgOn2;
imgOn{3} = imgOn3;
imgOn{4} = imgOn4;

%# setup axes
hAx = zeros(1,NUM);
hImg = zeros(1,NUM);
hAx = [handles.axes1 handles.axes2 handles.axes3 handles.axes4];
hImg(1) = imagesc(imgOff{1}, 'Parent',hAx(1));
hImg(2) = imagesc(imgOff{2}, 'Parent',hAx(2));
hImg(3) = imagesc(imgOff{3}, 'Parent',hAx(3));
hImg(4) = imagesc(imgOff{4}, 'Parent',hAx(4));
set(hAx, 'XTick',[], 'YTick',[],'Box', 'on')

%# get corner-points of each axis
set(hAx, 'Units','pixels')
axPos = cell2mat( get(hAx,'Position') );
disp(axPos)
p = zeros(5,2,NUM);
for k=1:NUM
    p(:,:,k) = bsxfun(@plus, axPos(k,1:2), ...
        [0 0; axPos(k,3) 0; axPos(k,3:4); 0 axPos(k,4); 0 0]);
end
handles.p = p;
handles.hAx = hAx;
handles.hImg = hImg;
handles.imgOff = imgOff;
handles.imgOn = imgOn;
% Update handles structure
guidata(hObject, handles);



function figure1_WindowButtonMotionFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to figure1 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

pos = get(hObject,'CurrentPoint');%CurrentPoint
posx = pos(1); posy = pos(2);

%Display to check to see if the position is working
posx = num2str(posx);
posy = num2str(posy);

set(handles.Xpos,'String',posx);
set(handles.Ypos,'String',posy);

p = handles.p;
hImg = handles.hImg;
hAx = handles.hAx;
imgOff = handles.imgOff;
imgOn = handles.imgOn;


%# for each axis, determine if we are inside it
    for i=1:numel(hImg)
        if inpolygon(pos(1),pos(2), p(:,1,i),p(:,2,i))
            set(hImg(i), 'CData',imgOn{i})
            set(hAx(i), 'LineWidth',3, 'XColor','r', 'YColor','r')
        else
            set(hImg(i), 'CData',imgOff{i})
            set(hAx(i), 'LineWidth',1, 'XColor','k', 'YColor','k')
        end
    end
```

[image]
These are the hitboxes is with the original code "set(hAx, 'Units','pixels')"

Note* the others are way off the screen to the top right, or would be.

[image]
These are the hitboxes with the altered code "set(hAx, 'Units','characters')"

Note* This is the exact same thing that happens when the code is commented out.

Tested Aug 2
.

.

.

.

***Addendum*** **Original Post**

I am getting this error after running my GUI [Fatal Error] :-1:-1: Premature end of file.

It happens during this block of code:

```
function figure1_WindowButtonMotionFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)

% hObject handle to figure1 (see GCBO)

% eventdata reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB

% handles structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

pos = get(hObject,'CurrentPoint');

%CurrentPoint

posx = pos(1); posy = pos(2);

%Display to check to see if the position is working

posx = num2str(posx); posy = num2str(posy);

 set(handles.Xpos,'String',posx); set(handles.Ypos,'String',posy);

%If mouse over then update the immage

if ((115 < pos(1)) && (pos(1) < 125) && (7 < pos(2)) && (pos(2) < 11))
axes(handles.axes1);
imshow('condH.png')  
else 
 axes(handles.axes1);
imshow('cond.png')

 end

 if ((90 < pos(1)) && (pos(1) < 100) && (7 < pos(2)) && (pos(2) < 11))
 axes(handles.axes2);
 imshow('compH.png')  
 else
axes(handles.axes2);
 imshow('comp.png')  
 end

if ((80 < pos(1)) && (pos(1) < 90) && (7 < pos(2)) && (pos(2) < 11))
axes(handles.axes3);
imshow('evapH.png')  
else
 axes(handles.axes3);
 imshow('evap.png')  
 end

if ((90 < pos(1)) && (pos(1) < 100) && (2 < pos(2)) && (pos(2) < 5))
axes(handles.axes4);
imshow('expH.png')  
else
 axes(handles.axes4);
 imshow('exp.png')  
end
```

Normally the GUI runs fine until I trigger one of the if statements by mousing over the predetermined box. Then the GUI stops responding and will not open again until Matlab is restarted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is difficult to tell why MATLAB is crashing without seeing your entire code. For this reason, I wrote the short example below. It illustrates how I would to write a GUI that simulates the [rollover effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rollover_%28web_design%29) using the [WindowButtonMotionFcn](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/figure_props.html#WindowButtonMotionFcn) callback:

```
function testRolloverGUI()
    %# prepare rollover image
    imgOff = imread('coins.png');
    imgOn = imcomplement(imgOff);

    %# setup figure
    hFig = figure('Resize','off', 'MenuBar','none', 'Color','w');
    set(hFig, 'WindowButtonMotionFcn',@figWindowButtonMotionFcn);
    hTxt = uicontrol('Style','text', 'String','(0,0)');

    %# setup axes
    NUM = 4;
    hAx = zeros(1,NUM);
    hImg = zeros(1,NUM);
    for k=1:NUM
        hAx(k) = subplot(2,2,k);
        hImg(k) = imagesc(imgOff, 'Parent',hAx(k));
    end
    colormap(gray)
    set(hAx, 'XTick',[], 'YTick',[], 'Box','on')

    %# get corner-points of each axis
    set(hAx, 'Units','pixels')
    axPos = cell2mat( get(hAx,'Position') );
    p = zeros(5,2,NUM);
    for k=1:NUM
        p(:,:,k) = bsxfun(@plus, axPos(k,1:2), ...
            [0 0; axPos(k,3) 0; axPos(k,3:4); 0 axPos(k,4); 0 0]);
    end

    %# callback function
    function figWindowButtonMotionFcn(hObj,ev)
        %# get mouse current position
        pos = get(hObj, 'CurrentPoint');
        set(hTxt, 'String',sprintf('(%g,%g)',pos))

        %# for each axis, determine if we are inside it
        for i=1:numel(hImg)
            if inpolygon(pos(1),pos(2), p(:,1,i),p(:,2,i))
                set(hImg(i), 'CData',imgOn)
                set(hAx(i), 'LineWidth',3, 'XColor','r', 'YColor','r')
            else
                set(hImg(i), 'CData',imgOff)
                set(hAx(i), 'LineWidth',1, 'XColor','k', 'YColor','k')
            end
        end
    end
end
```

[image: screenshot]

---

## EDIT#2

In response to your comments, I recreated the example in GUIDE. Here are the main parts:

```
%# --- Executes just before rollover is made visible.
function rollover_OpeningFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles, varargin)

    %# Choose default command line output for rollover
    handles.output = hObject;

    %# allocate
    NUM = 4;
    imgOff = cell(1,NUM);
    imgOn = cell(1,NUM);
    hImg = zeros(1,NUM);

    %# read images
    imgOff{1} = imread('coins.png');
    imgOn{1} = imcomplement(imread('coins.png'));
    imgOff{2} = imread('coins.png');
    imgOn{2} = imcomplement(imread('coins.png'));
    imgOff{3} = imread('coins.png');
    imgOn{3} = imcomplement(imread('coins.png'));
    imgOff{4} = imread('coins.png');
    imgOn{4} = imcomplement(imread('coins.png'));

    %# setup axes
    hAx = [handles.axes1 handles.axes2 handles.axes3 handles.axes4];
    for i=1:NUM
        hImg(i) = imagesc(imgOff{i}, 'Parent',hAx(i));
    end
    colormap(hObject, 'gray')
    set(hAx, 'XTick',[], 'YTick',[], 'Box','on')

    %# make sure axes units match that of the figure
    set(hAx, 'Units',get(hObject, 'Units'))

    %# check axes parent container (figure or panel)
    hAxParents = cell2mat( get(hAx,'Parent') );
    idx = ismember(get(hAxParents,'Type'), 'uipanel');
    ppos = cell2mat( get(hAxParents(idx), 'Position') );

    %# adjust position relative to parent container
    axPos = cell2mat( get(hAx,'Position') );
    axPos(idx,1:2) = axPos(idx,1:2) + ppos(:,1:2);

    %# compute corner-points of each axis
    p = zeros(5,2,NUM);
    for k=1:NUM
        p(:,:,k) = bsxfun(@plus, axPos(k,1:2), ...
            [0 0; axPos(k,3) 0; axPos(k,3:4); 0 axPos(k,4); 0 0]);
    end

    %# store in handles structure
    handles.p = p;
    handles.hAx = hAx;
    handles.hImg = hImg;
    handles.imgOff = imgOff;
    handles.imgOn = imgOn;

    %# Update handles structure
    guidata(hObject, handles);


%# --- Executes on mouse motion over figure - except title and menu.
function figure1_WindowButtonMotionFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)

    %# CurrentPoint
    pos = get(hObject,'CurrentPoint');
    set(handles.text1,'String',sprintf('(%g,%g)',pos));

    %# for each axis, determine if we are inside it
    for i=1:numel(handles.hImg)
        if inpolygon(pos(1),pos(2), handles.p(:,1,i),handles.p(:,2,i))
            set(handles.hImg(i), 'CData',handles.imgOn{i})
            set(handles.hAx(i), 'LineWidth',3, 'XColor','r', 'YColor','r')
        else
            set(handles.hImg(i), 'CData',handles.imgOff{i})
            set(handles.hAx(i), 'LineWidth',1, 'XColor','k', 'YColor','k')
        end
    end
```

The GUI has basically the same components as before, except that the axes are contained inside a `uipanel` (similar to the screenshot of your GUI):

[image: GUIDE]

A few things to note:

- Since our goal is to compare the figure's `CurrentPoint` to the axes position, it is important that they have the same `Units` as that of the figure, thus: `set(hAx, 'Units',get(hObject, 'Units'))`
- According to the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/axes_props.html#Position), an axis `Position` property is relative to its parent container, and because the four axes are inside a panel, we need to adjust their positions accordingly: `axPos(idx,1:2) = axPos(idx,1:2) + ppos(:,1:2);`

[image: GUI_in_action]

Comment: Ok. I don't know if you would like to see the whole code or not but for this sample code, how would I modify this to work with the GUIDE pre-made axes'es and figure?

Comment: And in such a way that they are open functions, because it is 'illegal' to have both types

Comment: @CMacDady: it should be similar: The first part is where I setup the figure and axes programmatically. This can be done using GUIDE and the property inspector. Note that it would be best to read and store the images once in the figure's initialization function. Next you would setup the `WindowButtonMotionFcn` callback as shown above. It is faster to simply update the `CData` of the image than to redraw it from scratch like you are doing. Finally, I was using the `INPOLYGON` function, but you can keep the tests you had if you like...

Comment: Ok so for the callback. Every time the `WindowButtonMotionFcn` is called it cycles through each area via the for loop.
However, you stored 4 subplots in one matrix, then 4 images belonging to the subplots... I have premade axes'es
Could I do something like hAx(1) = axes1; hAx(2) = axes2;  ?

Comment: @CMacDady: yes absolutely, that was just for convenience. In your case, you can do: `hAx = [handles.axes1 handles.axes2 handles.axes3];`

Comment: Ok wonderful. I will try implement this method then. Also I have everything up to the 'get corner axis' in the start up function correct?

Comment: Wait..no then p would be undefined cause the functions are separate.
How will the data transfer from start up function to the `WindowButtonMotionFcn`

Comment: @CMacDady: in the example above I am using nested functions to access data in the parent context. In [GUIDE-generated](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/creating_guis/f5-998352.html#f5-998711) figures, use the `handles` structure which gets passed around to all callback functions. So you will have to store any data you will later need inside this structure: `handles.p = []; guidata(hObject, handles);`

Comment: OK. I get it. Handles are like a global structure used to store data between functions. Ok let me play with my program and see if I can make this work.

Comment: At the very end of the opening function can I go handles.p = p; after doing everything that I want to to p?

In the same respect in the function I want to call it, at the beginning go p = handles.p ; ?

Comment: yes but also remember to call `guidata(hObject, handles)` at the end of the opening function. You really should take some time and read the documentation: http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/creating_guis/f5-998352.html

Comment: I will read through that though I did have guidata(hObject, handles).

The program runs without error now although the 'activation box' is way off from where it should be.

Comment: The axPos = cell2mat( get(hAx,'Position') ); is returning values that are way off from where the axis really are. 
Is everything being evaluated in pixels? I don't see why it returns correct values for your subplots and not the axis.
Or rather it is returning the points, but the axis position on the GUIDE display is different than what 'currentpoint' returns.
How can I align these.

Comment: @CMacDady: make sure you are working with the same units: `set(hAx,'Units','pixels')` maybe?

Comment: Ya I have that code pasted where you had it. While its there axPos = cell2mat( get(hAx,'Position') ) returns the GUIDE co ordinate values which are much larger. When I comment it out the co ordinates are almost the same but shifted about 60 or so pixels to the left for each one.

Comment: @CMacDady: that's it, glad you figured it out. If you look at the "get corner-points" section, I was building `p` by adding width/height to get the corner points, since it was required by the `INPOLYGON` function..

Comment: Oh, so you have already taken adding the width and height into consideration... then I have no idea why the co ordinates are so off.

Comment: @CMacDady: I'm afraid this is getting hard to follow.. Can you edit your question and post what you have done so far?

Comment: @CMacDady: I'm looking into it, but in the mean time, you should restore the old stuff back, and put your edits as an addendum. That way future readers will understand the original question...

Comment: I won't have access to matlab or my code until Tuesday from here on out. I would like to thank you for all the help you have provided me now though. So far it has helped me understand GUIs with greater insight.

Comment: @CMacDady: Glad I could help. BTW I think I know what the problem is; when we generate a GUI in GUIDE, by default the figure has `units=characters`, unlike the programmatically-generated ones which defaults to `units=pixels`... Long story short, change the line I previously mentioned to: `set(hAx,'Units','characters')` so that all units match.

Comment: By using that code the GUI is still doing what was mentioned above with the original line of code commented out. (Basically shifted ~60 pixels to the left.)
set(hAx,'Units','characters') in this case would be redundancy and the issue still stands.

Comment: @CMacDady: Please double-check as I am certain it is what's causing the problem... I have edited my solution to show the GUIDE-based solution, which I tested to work as expected

Comment: I double checked and ran the program with the updated code. I posted what I am seeing in the OP. While the hitboxes are better as far as units are concerned they are still off centered.

Comment: @CMacDady: seeing the GUI you designed, you forgot to mention that your axes are contained in a panel. See my new edit for a solution to the problem... This discussion has gone a bit long, I hope this finally solves your problem :)